# Calculating confidence interval of a combination of variables of different distributions?

Tags: confidence-interval

Once or twice a year, we go through an elaborate and expensive process to measure leakage in a pipe.  We calculate leakage via mass balance, so that:

\begin{equation}
    Leak = X + Y - Z
\end{equation}

Depending on how well data was collected for each variable, we select particular assumptions.  For example, we might assume Z to be uniformly distributed, while X & Y are normally distributed.

The end goal is to calculate the confidence interval of the estimated leak.

After calculating $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\sigma}$ for each variable, it's tempting to assume that $Leak$ is normally distributed, just because deriving the confidence interval is straight forward.  I just need to calculate $t_{\alpha/2}$, and define the confidence interval as $\mu_{Leak} \pm t_{\alpha/2}\hat{\sigma}_{Leak}$.  But this a pretty bad assumption, as $Leak$ is not normally distributed because $Z$ is uniformly distributed.  Any clues on how to calculate this confidence interval?

## Update:

I used simulation, as @soakey suggested, to generate 10k-sized samples for each historical event, and calculating the confidence interval was a matter of calculating the $(\alpha/2)^{th}$ and the $(1-\alpha/2)^{th}$ percentiles.

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from simulating?

Comment: Re (1): It is impossible for a uniform variate and a normal variate to have a correlation of $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @whuber.  You made me realize a flaw in my analysis.  I thought Y and Z should have been correlated because if we close the valve affecting Y, flow will change proportionally in Z.  But this is a mistake, because one of the conditions for my measurement is that no changes should be done to the state of system during data collection.  I think I can safely consider them independent.

Comment: @soakey, thanks for the idea!  I can probably just simulate the three variables jointly and estimate the pdf.  I will give it a try.

Comment: You should modify your question to reflect your new understanding. [Note for future reference, however, that '*what doesn't go through Z must go through Y*' would tend to imply negative, not positive correlation -- since the statement implies they must add to a constant, the present flow]